# Java — Loop create directories by number

Tags: java, io, directory

So my issue is that I would like to have my directories loop like this:
https://gyazo.com/74209ec6e199adc3cd84460f7e0d5c2e

My code for creating the dirs's:

```
public static File createDir(String path, String name) {
    File dir = new File(path + "\\" + name);
    dir.mkdir();
    return dir;

}

public static void createDirs(String path, int times) {
    int x;
    for(x=1; x < times+1; x++){
        Utils.createDir(path+File.separator, Integer.toString(x));
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Utils.createDir(System.getProperties().getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"Desktop", "Dir");
    createDirs(System.getProperties().getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"Desktop"+File.separator+"Dir", 10);
}
```

}

But I am not sure how to make it. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: It looks like this right now:
https://gyazo.com/e4877b87c6d9e1910bad7849daafd431

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `path` variable inside of the loop of `createDirs`

```
public static void createDirs(String path, int times) {
    int x;
    for(x=1; x < times+1; x++){
        path += File.separator + Integer.toString(x);
        new File(path).mkdir();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zain Drozal this is the modified code that you exactly want

```
package stack;

import java.io.File;

public class Utils {
  static File lastDir;

  public static File createDir(String path, String name) {
    File dir = new File(path + "\\" + name);
    dir.mkdir();
    return dir;
  }

  public static void createDirs(String path, int times) {
    int x;
    for(x=1; x < times+1; x++){
     lastDir = Utils.createDir(lastDir.getPath()+File.separator, Integer.toString(x));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    lastDir = Utils.createDir(System.getProperties().getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"Desktop", "Dir");
    createDirs(System.getProperties().getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"Desktop"+File.separator+"Dir", 10);
  }
}
```